# Mobile compatible/hybrid web application in MVC3/4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am creating an web application for user to manage their schedule. It will be MVC3/4 application. I want to know what will be the best approach to make it as mobile compatible also.

I read few articles online like using a phone gap,Kendo UI or a HTML 5 responsive view etc.Well i would love to try it all but dont ahve enough time to try it all.So what will be the best approach   to handle this problem. Website will basic login,registration,Grids for data information and maybe a google calender intrigation for scheduling. User will be using this website on their desktop and also on their mobile devices.

Thanks in advance,
Arpan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will definitely go with ASP.NET MVC 4 and jQuery Mobile

Since you are already building a web application, ASP.NET MVC 4 and jQuery Mobile will allow you to reuse your current model and controllers, and just build the presentation layer for mobile, you don't even have to take care of deciding which view to show to each device, MVC 4 will select the correct view when accessed from a mobile browser.

Note that this proposal implicitly chooses HTML5.

Kendo UI is a tool that will save time for complex controls like the schedule you plan to build, but it is not a different technology and you can add these controls later when you really need them.

Once your application is mature enough, then you can build a Native App to have better interoperation with the smartphone's own schedule, contacts and other features. When that moment arrives check out Xamarin that will allow you to build for any mobile platform using your existing C# knowledge. But do that later, start with the browser based version until the app mature.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into these options as you suggested.